# How can I stop Spring JPA from escaping the arguments to a query method?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

In my Spring JPA application, I have a query method called findAllByNameContaining that works for simple, one word arguments.

For instance, with a record in the database having a field value of 'Foo bar zed', the query method will return the record if called with 'Foo'.

However, I'd like the record to be retured if the query method is called with 'Foo zed'. I tried to replace spaces in the search term with '%'. This returned nothing and when I checked the generated SQL, I see that the '%' that I added to the search term was escaped. I understand this is likely to be protection against SQL injection, but I was wondering if there's anyway to stop Sopring escaping. I can validate the arguments myself to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: Containing, containingIgnoreCase, startsWith, endsWith might indeed escape % and _, but `like` not, requiring %...% though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `findByNameLike` instead and put the wildcards in the argument where ever you want.

Note that you have to provide all wildcards in the argument, Spring Data won't add any on its own but it won't escape any either.